# Universal group on $\kappa$ elements

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

It is well known that for every positive cardinal $\kappa$, every group of cardinality $\kappa$ can be embedded into $\text{Sym}(\kappa)$, the group of bijections on $\kappa$ with composition as group operation.

Is there an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ and a group $U$ of cardinality $\kappa$ such that every group of cardinality $\kappa$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $U$?

Comment: Just for context, the answer is no for $\kappa<2^{\aleph_0}$, using that there exists continuum many non-isomorphic finitely generated groups, and that each countable group embeds in one of them.

Comment: For $\kappa=2^{\aleph_0}$, I think this is an open question. Actually, concerning the group $G=\mathrm{Sym}(\aleph_0)/\mathrm{fin}$, the question whether every group of continuum cardinal embeds into $G$ is open, and is also open in ZFC+CH; in (ZFC + $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_2$) it consistently has a negative answer.

Comment: Jónsson (1956) [proved that](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/10468) under GCH, the answer is yes for every uncountable $\kappa$, see Theorem 3.1 therein. However to get the result for a single $\kappa$ probably does not require GCH, see notably Theorem 2.9 (unfortunately I can't find a definition for $\mathfrak{n}_\mu$ used there, so I'm not sure of meaning of the assumption).

Comment: Quoting from page 3 of [Banach spaces and groups - order properties and universal models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0303325.pdf) by Shelah and Usvyatsov: "Note that every AEC with amalgamation has a universal model in every regular $\lambda$ satisfying $\lambda=\lambda^{<\lambda}$ or $\lambda=\mu^+$ and $2^{<\mu}\leq\lambda$." 
So it seems one could take $\lambda=\beth_\omega^+$.

Comment: @YCor: Continuum of *finitely* generated groups?

Comment: @AsafKaragila yes this is what I wrote.

Comment: @YCor: Since there are only countably many formulas in the language of groups, I'm not sure how you'd make this calculation. Are you sure?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, I am, it's no contradiction. Continuum many pairwise non-isomorphic 2-generated groups. And since you talk about formulas, continuum pairwise non-elementary equivalent 2-generated groups. Precisely for every set $J$ of primes there exists a 2-generated group $G$ in which for $p$ prime, the formula $\exists g\neq 1:g^p=1$ holds in $G$ iff $p\in J$.

Comment: @Asaf You can have infinitely presented, finitely generated, groups. You can arrange for them to be nonisomorphic too (for example by some small cancellation theory, although there are other constructions). Also there are embedding theorems where you can arrange that for any countably group there is an  embedding into a 2-generated group.

Comment: @Paul: That was the bit I was missing, *infinitely presented*. Thanks!